# OpenMPI error when using more than 3 hosts

Tags: python, ssh, mpi, mpi4py

I ran a simple MPI Python program with more than 3 processes.
For example:

```
mpiexec -host master,w1,w2,w3 python code.py
```

It causes an error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname w3: Name or service not known
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.

This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (-tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
(e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
and network routing requirements).
```

However, if I ran the program with any two of w1,w2,w3, it works. EX:

```
mpiexec -host master,w1,w3 python code.py
```

And, this is the code

```
import random
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.rank
size = comm.size

if rank ==0:
print rank, 'worker'
else:
print rank, 'worker'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: 1. Try to run something simpler, not a Python script, but say `/bin/true/`. 2. Try to run it as `mpiexec -v -host...` and report the output.

Comment: sorry, how to run /bin/true ?

Comment: `mpirun /bin/true` or run whatever you like, but something simple. Don't forget the `-v` flag.

Comment: THX. I just ran `mpirun -v -host master,w1,w2,w3 /bin/true` and result is the same as I mentioned in the problem.

Comment: Didn't the `-v` print more details?

Comment: Not really. Only the details I have shown.

Comment: Sorry. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Do some more tests. Skip the Python part, because it is not an mpi4py problem, it is an OpenMPI or interconnect problem. Test exactly which nodes can be used together. Tell use how they are connected, which Infiniband layer you use, which exact OpenMPI version is it... Contact your network admin for support. If you are the admin, I don't know, my knowledge is not that good to know the cause.